# Table of SQL Errors & Stored Procedures

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have this bit of code I found on the web at the end of each of my stored procedures:

```
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

         PRINT '-----START: ERROR DETAILS-----'
         PRINT ERROR_NUMBER()
         PRINT ERROR_SEVERITY()
         PRINT ERROR_STATE()
         PRINT ERROR_PROCEDURE()
         PRINT ERROR_LINE()
         PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE()
         PRINT '-----END: ERROR DETAILS-----'

            DECLARE @prmErrmsg NVARCHAR(4000);
            DECLARE @prmErrSvr INT;

            SELECT @prmErrmsg = ERROR_MESSAGE()
                ,@prmErrSvr = ERROR_SEVERITY();

            INSERT INTO dbo.myErrors
                        ([ErrorMessage]
                        ,[ErrorSeverity]
                        ,[DateCreated])
                 VALUES
                        (@prmErrmsg
                        ,@prmErrSvr
                        ,GetutcDate())


            RAISERROR(@prmErrmsg,@prmErrSvr,1)
```

It's writing entries to the myErrors table, but it's not writing an error message or an error severity.

My first question is why?

I believe it's got something to with the error severity being within a certain range.

How can I tell it to log verbose error messages ALWAYS, regardless of severity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190358.aspx), ERROR_MESSAGE() etc are only set within the CATCH block of a TRY ... CATCH statement.